# Cant login to Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Every time i reset & seed my database it wipes out the standard admin@example.com login for Active Admin.

In my seed file i set a user as having role :admin but this login only works for the frontend of the app and not the backend active admin login. How can i remedy this? Thanks!

Note* Im using Devise + cancan + rolify

Seeds.rb

```
user2 = User.create! :name => 'Second User', :email => 'user2@example.com', :password => 'please', :password_confirmation => 'please', :confirmed_at => Time.now.utc
puts 'New user created: ' << user2.name
user.add_role :admin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Active Admin generally has another table for users known as admin_users. Please try the following in your console

```
user = AdminUser.create :email => 'user2@example.com', :password => 'please'
```

Comment: New to activeadmin. is this version mismatch:
``` user = AdminUser.create :email => 'user2@example.com', :password => 'please'
NoMethodError: undefined method `will_save_change_to_email?' for #<AdminUser:0x007fef27c66b00>
Did you mean?  will_save_change?
 from (irb):13
2.4.1 :014 >```