# Can't login to ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm facing issues logging in to ActiveAdmin. Using solutions from  [Can't log into Active Admin. Any way to create an admin user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447006/cant-log-into-active-admin-any-way-to-create-an-admin-user) and [Cant login to Active Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074806/cant-login-to-active-admin),

I tried running the following in my `rails console`

```
user = AdminUser.new
user.email = 'abc@example.com'
user.password = 'new_password'
user.save
```

On `user.save`, it gives me the following message:

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
AdminUser Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."email" = 'abc@example.com' LIMIT 1
false
(1.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

As far as I understand, this failed to create the record, correct?

I also tried the following solution:

```
AdminUser.create :email => 'abc1@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'
```

This gives the following message in the console:

```
    (0.0ms)  begin transaction
AdminUser Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."email" = 'ss1@example.com' LIMIT 1
SQL (11.0ms)  INSERT INTO "admin_users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 26 Aug 2014 05:41:42 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", "ss1@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$zLnnk8N3wx9GRb874YjjzOHukteF/qRjWPQMFTZOr7NMepljRRqOC"], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["updated_at", Tue, 26 Aug 2014 05:41:42 UTC +00:00]]
(138.9ms)  commit transaction


#<AdminUser id: 3, email: "ss1@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$zLnnk8N3wx9GRb874YjjzOHukteF/qRjWPQMFTZOr7NM...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 05:41:42", updated_at: "2014-08-26 05:41:42">
```

EDIT:

Also tried dropping and creating all models as follows:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

However, it still fails to login because of invalid username or password. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have u tried this - user = AdminUser.create :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'user123'

Comment: @CaffeineCoder this gives me `NameError: uninitialized constant AdminUser`

Answer (score 2):

You probably already figured this out... but DON'T FOLLOW ACTIVEADMIN'S GUIDE IF YOU'RE USING DEVISE!  It's not gonna work... (They REALLY need to revise their Readme... it's been... YEARS.)

Anyway the problem is that the user MUST exist in both Users and AdminUsers.  I didn't have this problem when I setup ActiveAdmin the first time because there was simply a boolean in the guide I was using where you could check or uncheck if a user was an admin user or not. (It was more difficult to setup but a MUCH more sensible way of doing things.

Anyway you just need to go to a rails console and instead of this:

```
AdminUser.create :email => 'abc1@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'
```

..do THIS:

```
User.create :email => 'abc1@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'
```

Problem solved!

Comment: agreed I think its a better solution to use the `rails g active_admin:install --skip-users` installation command and then add a boolean property to devise User to toggle admin feature access

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue, and I solved this.

```
$ rake db:seed
$ rails runner "puts AdminUser.count"  # should be => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows that you are using username as authentication key `invalid username or password` and you are trying to logged in with email. Your table structure shows that you are using devise for authentication. So there must be some problem in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`. try use

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email, :username ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email, :username ]
```

Some other changes may also required. Have a look at devise gem for this.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This didn't really solve it for me. As I'm still facing the error. I'm quite new to rails so if you could make it a little clearer, I should be able to sort it.

Comment: try find `config.case_insensitive_keys` in your `config/intializers/devise.rb` file and if you find `:username` there then replace it with `[ :email, :username ]`

Comment: It's currently `config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]`. Changing this to `[ :email, :username ]` and restarting server didn't help.

Comment: same here non solution yet :(