# ActiveAdmin 401 Unauthorized Can't Login using default or created users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I've been running activeadmin for years on my old app, but I'm just creating a new rails 4.2 app from scratch and I've installed activeadmin, and migrated and seeded the database... but it simply won't let me login (gives me the "invalid password" thing).

Below is the complete error:

```
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"edCCf/+TsRq7AVXY8/xMW9ytFvb/9Rk1wNte3EC9CMvrPAuiLdEtzePXlsZ+QV1Md2jbcKFgojg72uLtya996g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "admin@example.com"]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

And in the off chance you want to see the rest:

```
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"edCCf/+TsRq7AVXY8/xMW9ytFvb/9Rk1wNte3EC9CMvrPAuiLdEtzePXlsZ+QV1Md2jbcKFgojg72uLtya996g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  Rendered /Users/rainless/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-557d143e8a48/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/rainless/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-557d143e8a48/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (23.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 194ms (Views: 119.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The user exists, I can only imagine that the password is, in fact, "password"... but just in case I also created my own admin user and couldn't login with that either.  I even went so far as to make a user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    User.create(user_params)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_remember, :id)
  end
end
```

...to specifically allow email and password and id and everything else... no avail.

Also did everything this guy did:

[Can't login to ActiveAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498878/cant-login-to-activeadmin)

Absolutely nothing has helped.

Rails version is 4.2.5

ActiveAdmin is: activeadmin (1.0.0.pre2 557d143)
Devise is: devise (3.5.5)

Please help

Comment: What do you have in your config/initializers/active_admin.rb file? On the line that says "config.authentication_method"

Comment: The default: "authenticate_user!" But I already solved the problem below. I was "following the directions" instead of thinking it through. So I wound up creating both "AdminUser" and "User" through activeadmin. And it doesn't seed "User"... only "AdminUser".  So you just have to create the user manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about the most complete version of the problem and the solution that you're likely to find here.

The problem is that the user MUST exist in both Users and AdminUsers.  I didn't have this problem when I setup ActiveAdmin the first time because there was simply a boolean in the guide I was using where you could check or uncheck if a user was an admin user or not. (It was more difficult to setup but a MUCH more sensible way of doing things.

Anyway you just need to go to a rails console and instead of this:

```
AdminUser.create :email => 'abc1@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'
```

..do THIS:

```
User.create :email => 'abc1@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'
```